# Test values inside JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have this JSON in a file:

```
{"groupcolor":[
    {"user":"group01", "color":"blue"},
    {"user":"group02", "color":"yellow"},
    {"user":"group03", "color":"green"}
]}
```

and I want to use Python(3) to verify if the content of "user" matches with "color". I've tried:

```
import json 

with open('groupcolor.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        if f.user == group01 and f.color = blue:
            print("ok!")
        else:
            print ("not ok")
```

but it obviously isn't the right syntax. most of the information that I found is focused on parsing or adding information, but I haven't found anything about checking the relation between two elements. is a way to do it in Python?

Comment: you might want to parse content first: `import json; json.loads(f) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely have the right idea: just the wrong syntax, as you point out.

As a comment suggests, you need to use `json.load()` (but not `json.loads()`, as `json.loads()` is for a string, not a file). This will rope in the json file as a dictionary.

```
import json 

with open('groupcolor.json') as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)
    users = json_dict["groupcolor"]
    for item in users:
        if item["user"] == "group01" and item["color"] == "blue":
            print("ok!")
        else:
            print ("not ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
import json 

with open('groupcolor.json') as f:
    group_color = json.load(f)  # parse json into dict

group_color = group_color["groupcolor"]  # get array out of dict

# create a dictionary where user is group01 and color is blue
search_criteria = dict(zip(("user", "color"), ("group01", "blue")))
for user_data in group_color:
    message = "ok!" if user_data == search_criteria else "not ok"
    print(message)
```